# How to compare text feild password with database md5 password.?

Tags: php, mysql

I want, the user will login when the username and password text field matched with database username and password.i stored md5() password in database.now to to compare the text field password and database md5 format password.

index.html

```
> <form name="f1" action="login.php" method="post"> <table border="1">
> <tr><td>username</td><td><input type="text" name="t1"></td></tr>
> <tr><td>password</td><td><input type="password" name="t2"></td></tr>
> <tr><td><input type="submit" value="login"></td></tr> </table> </form>
```

login.php

```
$user=$_POST['t1'];
$pass=md5($_POST['t2']);
$result=mysql_query("select * from registor where username='$user' and password='$pass'")or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

it is not working.the password text field not matched with md5 ? how ?

Comment: Why are new developers still using md5 for passwords in 2013? Why are new developers still using MySQL (rather than MySQLi or PDO) in 2013?

Comment: +1 on Mark Bakers comment, OP, please check out the following links. Do the right thing from the start!  
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php  
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php  
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

Is doing this the trick:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from registor where username='$user' and password=md5('$pass');")or die(mysql_error());
```

Based on docu from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add md5 inside query.

```
$user=$_POST['t1'];
$pass=md5($_POST['t2']);
$result=mysql_query("select * from registor where username='$user' and    
 password=md5('$pass')")or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Note: Try to use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly off on tangent but if possible you shout NOT be using md5 to store hashed passwords. Especially without salt. A good starting points for more information on this are:

http://ircmaxell.github.io/password-hashing-mini-presentation/
http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing